# Solr edismax query parser handling of stopwords

Tags: solr, lucene

I set up the solr example techproducts in solr 7.2.1 and made one change: I found the stopwords.txt file and added "a" as a stopword.  Next, I issue two queries in debug mode so I can see how the query parsed.

I tried two queries: "x a b" and "x b".

Here is the raw query:

```
q=x b&fl=id,score,price&sort=score desc&qf=name^0.75 manu cat^3.0 features^10.0&defType=edismax
```

and

```
q=x a b&fl=id,score,price&sort=score desc&qf=name^0.75 manu cat^3.0 features^10.0&defType=edismax
```

The idea is that I want different weights for the different fields, and I want to be able to take the score of each term from its best field, i.e. score the "x" from its match against the "cat" field and the "b" against the "features" field.

When I have "x b" I get this behavior exactly, with the parsed query as follows:

```
+(((name:x)^0.75 | manu:x | (features:x)^10.0 | (cat:x)^3.0) ((name:b)^0.75 | manu:b | (features:b)^10.0 | (cat:b)^3.0))
```

When I use "x a b" I instead get:

```
+((name:x name:b)^0.75 | (manu:x manu:b) | (features:x features:b)^10.0 | (cat:x cat:a cat:b)^3.0)
```

With the "x a b" query suppose document 1 matches "x" in "features" and matches "b" in "cat".  This document will get a single score based upon either its "x" or its "b", but the score will not be the sum, as would have been the case had the query been, "x b".

How do I get the edismax parser to behave the same for queries with stopwords as it does without stopwords, keeping the behavior constant for queries with no stopwords?

I also noticed that this does not seem to affect the dismax query parser - only the edismax query parser.

Comment: How are your `mm` and [`tie`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/the-dismax-query-parser.html#the-tie-tie-breaker-parameter) parameters set ? Did you try to play with [`mm.autorelax`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#extended-dismax-parameters) ?

Comment: I did not change either of those in the query nor did I edit them in the configuration files, so I would guess they are still at whatever the, "factory default" value is.